# Can I reuse the screws and holes of a ceiling rose to fit a surface mount light?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I'm moving into a new build and in some room. I have some simple pendant lights with a rose. Unscrewing the rose reveals a new box that seems to click in place and that hides all the connections and potentially the screws that are keeping it attached to the ceiling.

If I manage to remove this box, can I reuse the screws and the holes to fit a surface mount ceiling light or would I have to drill new holes? By the looks of it, the mount bracket seems to have both wide and narrow holes, and the latter might match the current holes.

[image: ceiling rose with pendant]

Comment: A photo would help us to understand how the mechanics of your fixture work.

Comment: I've added a photo of a similar product. I'll try to get an actual photo tomorrow.

Comment: Accroding to your profile you're in Scotland,  which explains the BC22 light socket in the photo. I'm  just mentioning this because  this will make a difference to the answer.

Comment: @AlaskaMan  It's a cord grip ceiling rose, the ones we use this side of the planet (Very distant from Scotland) include a terminal block for making the electrical connection.  A tough sheathed electrical cable comes in through the back and using the terminal block is connected to the lamp flex. some other mechanism grips the flex. so the physical load is not taken be the electrical connection.  they can be fixed to ceiling battens, or replace the cover on a circular electrical box.

Comment: I have updated the post with a photo of the actual pendant

Comment: Pardon my edits. "Flush mount" is a term often misused by lighting company marketing departments to sound fancy. They lie. In fact, flush things are even with the surface they're related to, not laid on top of them.